# What does jmp $ accomplish

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am busy following a tutorial on building a simple bootloader/os to better understand assembly, but I can't figure out what this accomplished

```
jmp $
times 510-($-$$)
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

I understand what the bottom two lines do, but what does the jmp $ do. To my current knowledge it means go to the current memory address, but the current memory address is holding the jmp instruction, so wouldn't it just jump to itself over and over and never execute the bottem code.

Comment: That is exactly right. It's an endless loop. The bottom code is not code, it's two signature bytes that the BIOS is checking to verify it's a boot sector. They are not instructions intended for the cpu to execute.

Comment: How are the bytes declared if the code is never executed?

Comment: It's the reverse. Bytes are declared and some get executed :) `jmp $` and `db 0x55` just tell the assembler what bytes to emit. For the `jmp $` it will be the machine code for the instruction. This happens at assembly time. Then at runtime some of those bytes will be fetched by the cpu and executed. The ones that are not are still there in memory however (think data).

Comment: So the bytes are declared at assembly time and then everything is executed

Comment: I think I understand it now, thanks allot for the help

Comment: Right, the assembler just reads a text file (.asm) and assembles bytes into an output file.  It doesn't simulate a CPU executing them.